# Make Form Transparent

Tags: c#, winforms, transparency

I am trying to make a transparent form that will be shown on the bottom right corner of the screen. In that form, I have an image as a background that I am rotating. The issue is, when I use the following code to make the form transparent, I am getting outlines on the image that is equivalent to the color I set for the transparency key/background. Is this because of the image, or is there a way to fix this programmatically?

CODE:

```
this.TransparencyKey = Color.Orange;
this.BackColor = Color.Orange;
```

This gives me an orange outline around my image.

Comment: That's because your image contains anti-aliasing, semi-transparent or semi-orange pixels. You need to get rid go them!

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make the border transparent but you can get rid of it altogether.
To get rid of the border you would use this.

```
FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
```